# Reading from text file using Jet Oledb with headers off (HDR=No)

Tags: csv, oledb, jet

I have CSV text file which I'm trying to read from my code into a Dataset. If the starting character is #, the code reads alternate columns.

[image: Dataset]

following is the code that I'm using.

```
DataSet dsFileRecords = new DataSet();
string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + filename + "";
OleDbConnection fileConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + decryptedFilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=NO;FMT=CSVDelimited;\"");
OleDbDataAdapter dsCmd = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectQuery, fileConnection);
//Fill the DataSet object
dsCmd.Fill(dsFileRecords, "ReconciliationRecords");
```

**Update**

I have updated my screenshot based on the suggested answer,

[image]

**Input Data**

```
#Header,TPCCH,LTPTP,TRC,F,2012/06/06 23:59:59,0000000002,0000000003,00.00,00.00,PTP0101011,PTP0101010 
011001001,0110212122,W,W1,2012/06/06 23:59:59,01100110,2L,10.00,,A,,AP09BK4890, 
011001002,0110212123,W,W1,2012/06/06 23:59:59,01100110,2L,10.00,10.00,AD,,AP09BK4890, 
011001003,0110212123,E,E1,2012/06/06 23:59:59,01100110,2L,10.00,10.00,R,012,AP09BK4891, #TRAILER,0000000003
```

Answer (score 3):

Sandeep, hashtag sing (`#`) isn't your issue here.

Since you turned off the headers, Jet engine interprets each column as the same data type. Say here

`#Header, 011001001, 011001002, 011001003` are in the same column and the format for `#header` is different than the rest so the engine rejects it.

The similar situation for the rest of the missing ones. If you notice this issue doesn't happen int he 3rd and 4th columns since they are of a same format.

To fix this issue turn your headers `ON` by changing `HDR=No` to `HDR=Yes` in your connection string and the first column will be treated differently and don't get used for data type recognition purposes.

To give you a little glimps of what is happening I have written a little console application to replicate the situation.

```
var file = new FileInfo("C:\\TextFile.txt");

OleDbConnection fileConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"" + file.DirectoryName + "\";Extended Properties='text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited(,)';");
string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + file.Name;

using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(selectQuery, fileConnection))
{
    fileConnection.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter dsCmd = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectQuery, fileConnection);
    //Fill the DataSet object
    DataSet dsFileRecords = new DataSet();
    dsCmd.Fill(dsFileRecords, "ReconciliationRecords");

    foreach (DataTable dsFileRecord in dsFileRecords.Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dsFileRecord.Rows)
        {
            foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine( "\r\n" );
        }
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

What I am going to test here are the contents of my **TextFile.txt**

If the contents are

```
#FName, LName, Phone 
Hank, Donald, 0202
Walter, W, 0203
Jimmy, Jones, 0201
```

The output is,

```
#FName
LName


Hank
Donald
202

Walter
W
203

Jimmy
Jones
201
```

If you noticed I also added # before the first header to clear up the suspension . Now you can see the the header ***Phone*** is missing, since all it's following row's values in the same column have a numerical value.

Now check this out. My TextFile.txt content as,

```
#FName, LName, Phone 
Hank, Donald, 0202
Walter, W, 0203
Jimmy, Jones, 0201
```

gives the output in the console app as,

```
#FName
LName
1111

Hank
Donald
202

Walter
W
203

Jimmy
Jones
201
```

How good is that?! The value `1111` that I have replaced for value `Phone` comes up fine. :)

Turn the headers `On` and add this chunk to your code inside the first `Foreach` and before the `rows` `Foreach` and you'll get your headers printed and sorted as bellow,

```
foreach (DataTable dsFileRecord in dsFileRecords.Tables)
{
    // Added foreach statement. 
    foreach (DataColumn column in dsFileRecord.Columns)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(column.ColumnName.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\r\n");

    foreach (DataRow row in dsFileRecord.Rows)
    {
        foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
    }
}
```

and the output is,

```
#FName
LName
Phone

Hank
Donald
202

Walter
W
203

Jimmy
Jones
201
```

Voila!

**Update**

`#Header` and `#Trailer` aren't part of your data, so then need to be removed before processing. A little Regex would do the trick (however if you don't know Regex ([Regular Expression Language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) this might look like a black magic).

This is the code need to be modified at the start

```
var file = new FileInfo("C:\\RealTextFile.txt");

// Regex to remove the "#Header" and "#Trailer".
// The modigied txt file will be saved with the "_" prefix.
File.WriteAllLines(file.DirectoryName + "\\_" + file.Name,
    File.ReadAllLines(file.FullName).Select(content =>
        Regex.Replace(content, @".*(?>#Header,)|#TRAILER.+", string.Empty)
    ));

file = new FileInfo(file.DirectoryName + "\\_" + file.Name);


OleDbConnection fileConnection = ...
```

Comment: I think this will help but it is not reading the float amount values.. check the new screen shot.

Comment: It's okay, I have fixed it for you. Let me look into it to see what's the problem with the float numbers you mentioned. @sandeep

Comment: @sandeep, I had a look at your screenshot and honestly don't have any idea what's going on. Would you be able to update your question the way I did to add the screeshot and this time include the original content of the text file or even part of it?

Comment: #Header,TPCCH,LTPTP,TRC,F,2012/06/06 23:59:59,0000000002,0000000003,00.00,00.00,PTP0101011,PTP0101010
011001001,0110212122,W,W1,2012/06/06 23:59:59,01100110,2L,10.00,,A,,AP09BK4890,
011001002,0110212123,W,W1,2012/06/06 23:59:59,01100110,2L,10.00,10.00,AD,,AP09BK4890,
011001003,0110212123,E,E1,2012/06/06 23:59:59,01100110,2L,10.00,10.00,R,012,AP09BK4891,
#TRAILER,0000000003

Comment: You got three problems here: **1**) `#header`&`#trailer` aren't part of your data so should be removed. Check my update on the answer. **2**)you got duplicate header names `00.00` and `00.00`. This can't happen in any DB system AFAIK since it will create two same name fields. **3**)Your header has dots `.` in it and they get translated to `#`. for solution on 2&3 check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28227665/1316651.