# querying Excel sheet with complex column names

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net

My excel sheet has complex column names such as:

```
6. Date of birth

Region (by Zip code)
```

With the next Vba code I am trying to query them but I get error an message as soon as I include

```
    [6. Date of birth], [Region (by Zip code)]
```

Is there a way to correct this without changing those column names? I need them to keep their explanatory nature.

```
    Sub processPatientInformation()
       '--- Declare Variables to store the connection, the result and the SQL query
        Dim connection As Object, result As Object, sql As String, recordCount As Integer
        '--- Connect to the current datasource of the Excel file
    Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    
    With connection
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
        .Open
    End With
    
  
    sql = "SELECT [Club ID], [Last Name], [First Name], [6. Date of birth], [Region (by Zip code)] FROM [players$A1:V184]"
            
    
    '--- Run the SQL query
    Set result = connection.Execute(sql)  
    
    



    Call Module1.createCSVfile(result, "C:\resultados.csv")
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Related?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687817/ace-oledb-provider-incorrectly-reads-some-column-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only NOT VALID in your headers is the dot [6. Date of birth] You can replace it like this [6) Date of birth]  and "keep their explanatory nature."

Comment: I just did not wanted to change any labels as it is the way I get them from the customer. Anyway, I was also curious about the limitations placed by the use of identifiers within [ ]

Comment: Also try: 1) change headers making them easy to use in SQL 2) run the SQL coded with the new headers 3) Copy back the original headers. If use Application.ScreenUpdating = False at the begining of the Sub, nobody will see the changing.

Answer (score 1):

This SQL will work:

```vb
sql = "SELECT [Club ID], [Last Name], [First Name], [6# Date of birth], " & _
      " [Region (by Zip code)] FROM [players$A1:V184]"
```

ie. *within the SQL* replace any "." in the column headers with "#" (your column header on the sheet can remain as e.g. `6. Date of birth`)

You'll need to do the reverse if you're writing out the field names from the recordset to a file...